# Unable to validate textarea when using within UpdatePanel and jQuery Form validation

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, textarea

I am using jquery form validation to validate form. Validation works perfect for textbox but it fails when trying to validate the textbox with textmode multiline. For information I am using updatepanel too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).bind("load", function () {
            $("#frmServiceRequest").validate({
                rules: {
                    txtDescription: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8
                    }
                }
            });
        });
        function pageLoad() {
            $('#txtDescription').attr('name', 'txtDescription');

        }
    </script>

<form id="frmServiceRequest" runat="server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager2" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="uPanelInfo" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div class="new-service-request-cancel-pop">
                        <h3 class="pop-heading">
                            <asp:Literal ID="litServiceRequest" Text="Service Request Cancellation" runat="server"></asp:Literal></h3>
                        <div id="divHeaderMessage" visible="false" runat="server" style="width: 100%; bottom: 0px;">
                           <p id="p">
                                <i id="imgStatusMsg" runat="server"></i>
                                <span class="divMessageContent">
                                    <asp:Literal ID="litStatusMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                </span>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div id="divMessageButton" class="message-button" runat="server" visible="false">
                            <button id="btnOK" type="button" value="Ok" class="orange-submit round-border-4"
                                onclick="closePopup();" style="font-weight: normal">
                                <asp:Literal ID="litOK" runat="server" Text="Ok"></asp:Literal>
                            </button>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnSourcePage" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Value="" />
                        </div>

                        <div id="formContent" runat="server">
                            <div class="form-area register-form">
                                <div class="service-request-cancel-pop-form fl pad-top5">
                                    <ul class="full fl">
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="lblRequestId" runat="server" Text="Request Id"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtRequestId" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnExpServiceDate" runat="server" />
                                            </label
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litSerialNumber" runat="server" Text="Serial #"></asp:Literal></label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtSerialNumber" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>                                        
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litUnitNumber" runat="server" Text="Unit #"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtUnitNumber" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>


                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="lblCancelReason" runat="server" Text="Cancel Reason"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:DropDownList CssClass="form-input-select round-border-4"
                                                ID="ddlCancelReasons" runat="server" TabIndex="1">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>
                                        </li>

                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="service-request-cancel-pop-form fr pad-top5">
                                    <ul class="full fl">
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litRequestType" runat="server" Text="Request Type"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtRequestType" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <%--<li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtName" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litCunstomerUnit" runat="server" Text="Customer Unit #"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtCustomerUnit" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>--%>

                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litModel" runat="server" Text="Model"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtModel" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>                                        
                                        <%--<li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litExpectedServiceDate" runat="server" Text="Expected Service Date"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtExpServiceDate" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>--%>
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="lblServiceCenter" runat="server" Text="Service Center"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="label-name-data">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="txtServiceCenter" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="full pad-bot10">
                                    <ul class="full fl">
                                        <li>
                                            <label class="form-label part-50">
                                                <asp:Literal ID="litDescription" runat="server" Text="Cancel Reason Description"></asp:Literal>
                                            </label>
                                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" TextMode="Multiline" 
                                                CssClass="txtarea round-border-4" ></asp:TextBox>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clear"></div>
                                <div class="full pad-top10 pop-btns">
                                    <div class="fr">
                                        <asp:Button CssClass="round-border-4 orange-submit" ID="btnSubmit" TabIndex="3" runat="server"
                                            Text="Confirm" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ClientIDMode="AutoID"/>
                                        <button id="btnCancel" class="orange-submit round-border-4 " onclick="closePopup();" 
                                            style="font-weight: normal">
                                            <asp:Literal ID="litCancel" runat="server" Text="Cancel"></asp:Literal>
                                        </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
            <asp:UpdateProgress ID="uppContentInfo" runat="server">
                <ProgressTemplate>
                    <div id="divProcessingRequest" runat="server" class="loading-overlay">
                        <div class="wrap-loader-dark-bg">
                            <img id="loading-dark" src="../images/loader-dark-bg.gif" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </ProgressTemplate>
            </asp:UpdateProgress>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCultureCode" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
        </form>
```

Comment: Could you provide us your code please?

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: The validation message is displayed for some time but form get submitted and code behind get executed.